# Can't access Craigslist even using the recommended bridges when I set up Tor on my pc

Tags: help

Can't access Craigslist even using the recommended bridges when I set up Tor on my pc.  Can anyone offer a solution?  Thank you.

Comment: why can Tor not fix this problem with a workaround? craigslist is not the only page blocked... :( should be something like a simulator/emulator of other browsers

Comment: That will never work, if a site wants to block Tor they will be able to block Tor and this isn't an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Craigslist actively blocks Tor exit nodes, so there is nothing you can do. Using bridges will not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

While for me accessing craigslist.org works using Tor Browser now, in cases of webservices that completely block Tor, you can only find a proxy you connect to *first*, that connects to the website then on your behalf. A simple test would be to search at startpage.com and use their "proxy" Link at your search result.

You other option would be to contact the website technical staff and discuss better (or, "actual") security measures than blocking traffic from the Tor network. Malicious traffic is everywhere, by far not only at Tor Exit Relays. If they block everything, they don't exists anymore, so...

Answer (score 0):

Jan 2022. Craigslist suddenly blocks all efforts to connect to it through Tor browser. If you are running Windows 10, you can try to release your existing IP with an instruction through the command prompt and then ask for a new IP address with another instruction through the command prompt.

To try this, right click the start icon and select command prompt(admin). You need to run the command prompt as an administrator. If you are asked whether you want to let the program make changes to your computer, click yes and wait for the command prompt window to show up. When it does, you should see a blinking cursor. At the blinking cursor, type "ipconfig /release" (without the quotes) and wait for the command to complete. This will release your IP address. Then, at the blinking cursor, type "ipconfig /renew" (without the quotes). This should give you a new IP address. Restart your computer. See if you can connect to Craigslist.

Comment: This will not change anything. The website would be blocking the Tor exit relay's IP address, not the user's IP address. To try a different exit, click the "New Circuit for this Site" button in the Tor Browser.